# Which RxJS operator should I use for getting the first true value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am building an Angular application and I have a route, protected with guard.
In the guard I have 3 boolean observables.

Each observable returns true or false values, depending on the application state/route etc.
I want that the guard returns true, if at least one observable returned true, otherwise - false.

So if at least one observables has evaluated to true - I want that the script should ignore others and the guard should return true

But if it returned false, the guard should look for the second observable and see its evaluated result.

I think that I could use `combineLatest`:

```
combineLatest([
   $obs1,
   $obs2,
   $obs3
])
```

and check result of each observable, but this code will run all three observables without cancellation.
the observables **may** run simultaneously, but they **must not complete** (if not already completed, if any of observables already returned `true`,
and should return `false` only if all of observables returns `false`).

Which operator should I use for getting the first `true` observable value, and ignoring others, but returning false if all observables returned `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve could be done with

```
merge(
 $obs1.pipe(first()),
 $obs2.pipe(first()),
 $obs3.pipe(first())
).pipe(
  filter(Boolean),
  take(1),
  defaultIfEmpty(false),
)
```

`filter(Boolean)` filters out `false` results, because there are probably yet not handled `true`s and we should continue searching.

`take(1)` will take the first `true` when found, because you really don't care about other trues if there is already one.

and if everything is false, then no events will be emmited by previous operator chain and therefore `defaultIfEmpty(false)` will put false in that place

Comment: I think yes, but can you please explain about the operators in the pipe ? like filter(Boolean). take(1) - will take only one emit, and why defaultIfEmpty(false) is needed? I will accept your answer, once you give me a fine explanation, thank you.

Comment: one more thing, something should be edited, because there is a type mismatch. the Guard must return and Observable of boolean (`Observable<boolean>`), but this thing returns `Observable<boolean | Observable<boolean>>` --> sometimes it returns not `boolean`, but **another** `Observable<boolean>`, can you provide a fix?

Comment: it seems i've messed up `merge`'s signature a bit and values should be passed without an array

Answer (score 0):

`combineLatest` should be what you want !

```
combineLatest([obs1$, obs2$, obs3$]).pipe(
  filter(([v1, v2, v3]) => {
    return v1 || v2 || v3 || (!v1 && !v2 && !v3);
  }),
  take(1)
);
```

Comment: As I wrote, in this case, all observable will return values, and then you compare them. But I don't need obs2 and obs3 results, if obs1 already returned `true`.

Comment: `filter(filterCallback) + take(1)` could be replaced with `first(filterCallback)`. it is not 100% the same, but most likely it would be the same in current scenario

Comment: I can return just `Array.some(result)` :), but as I wrote, the `combineLatest` is not the ideal approach, since it uses all observable values, but I need only the first `true` value.